# What are the 49 curses and the 98 curses?

Tags: curse, ki-tavo, bechukosai

Specifically, I am looking for an official list and breakdown of both sets of curses so I can compare the two. And ideally an existing comparison of both.

I know there are 49 in Vayikra (parsha Bechukotai starting with [26:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.26.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) and 98 in Devarim (parsha Ki Tavo starting with [28:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.28.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=enand)), but I can't seem to find a list in any of the commentaries.

Comment: Rashi in Vayikra counts most (if not all) of the 49

Comment: When lists get beyond 5 or 6, I typically just go with "if you say so".  It's very hard to keep 147 data points organized in your head at the same time.

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for an official list of each set of curses. I know someone already counted them all because they're exactly 49 in source and 98 in another. I can make the comparison myself, I have basic compréhension skills, but if someone else already has that information would be swell. I was just providing context to why I am asking because this website said my question was too short.