# Where are the last fourteen of the 49 curses in Bechukosai, Rashi only lists 5 sets of 7?

Tags: rashi, parsha-torah-portion, bechukosai

Rashi in the beginning of pashas Netzavim writes, that there are 49 curses in parshas Bechukosai - ["besides the forty-nine that are contained in Torath-Cohanim"] . When you go through the Rashi in Parshas Bechukosai, you find that he only enumerates 5 sets of 7, [they are: set 1 = pesukim 16-17, set 2 = 18-20, set 3 = 21-22, set 4 = 23-25, set 5 = 27-32] which equal 35? What and where are the missing curses?

[This question is different than [What are the 49 curses and the 98 curses?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/98364/what-are-the-49-curses-and-the-98-curses), since I am only looking for the last 14 curses in Bechukosai.]

Comment: I don't know if this is significant, but when we read them, we've usually counted around 35/49 days

Comment: Even though there are curses after pasuk 32, the most I came up with is 12 not 14. [Pasuk 33 = 3, 36 =3, 37 = 3, 38 = 2, 39 = 1, and 41 = 1]

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not canon, but just for the fun of it I asked chatgbt for "Just a list of all the curses in Leviticus 26" and this is the exact response:

Certainly! Here is a list of all the curses mentioned in Leviticus 26:14-46:

1. Disease and wasting away (Leviticus 26:16)
2. Fever and inflammation (Leviticus 26:16)
3. Constant defeat by enemies (Leviticus 26:17)
4. Famine and food scarcity (Leviticus 26:19)
5. Defeat and oppression by enemies (Leviticus 26:20)
6. Wild animals killing livestock and children (Leviticus 26:22)
7. Pestilence and disease (Leviticus 26:25)
8. Defeat and capture by enemies (Leviticus 26:25)
9. Violence and destruction (Leviticus 26:31)
10. Desolation of cities and sanctuaries (Leviticus 26:31)
11. Destruction of idols and altars (Leviticus 26:30)
12. Exile and scattering among nations (Leviticus 26:33)
13. Loss of land and inheritance (Leviticus 26:34)
14. Defeat and subjugation by enemies (Leviticus 26:37)
15. Fear and fleeing from imagined threats (Leviticus 26:36)
16. Loss of strength and power (Leviticus 26:37)
17. Loss of crops and harvest (Leviticus 26:20)
18. Hunger and starvation (Leviticus 26:26)
19. Cannibalism (Leviticus 26:29)
20. Desperation and defeat (Leviticus 26:36)
21. Loss of sons and daughters (Leviticus 26:22)
22. Despair and hopelessness (Leviticus 26:36)
23. Defeat and humiliation by enemies (Leviticus 26:43)
24. Destruction of cities and fortified places (Leviticus 26:31)
25. Devastation of the land (Leviticus 26:33)
26. Destruction of crops and fruit trees (Leviticus 26:16)
27. Loss of livestock and flocks (Leviticus 26:22)
28. Drought and scarcity of water (Leviticus 26:19)
29. Loss of dignity and honor (Leviticus 26:43)
30. Desolation and destruction of land (Leviticus 26:32)
31. Fear and terror (Leviticus 26:36)
32. Loss of strength and vitality (Leviticus 26:20)
33. Defeat and overthrow by enemies (Leviticus 26:17)
34. Sickness and disease (Leviticus 26:16)
35. Childlessness and barrenness (Leviticus 26:22)
36. Ruin and desolation (Leviticus 26:31)
37. Defeat and oppression by enemies (Leviticus 26:37)
38. Captivity and bondage (Leviticus 26:33)
39. Destruction of cities and dwellings (Leviticus 26:31)
40. Reproach and shame (Leviticus 26:43)
41. Broken covenant and rejection by God (Leviticus 26:44)
42. Loss of land and inheritance (Leviticus 26:41)
43. Exile and scattering among nations (Leviticus 26:33)
44. Desolation and destruction of land (Leviticus 26:33)
45. Defeat and captivity by enemies (Leviticus 26:38)
46. Fear and fleeing from imagined threats (Leviticus 26:17)
47. Loss of possessions and wealth (Leviticus 26:16)
48. Loss of crops, fruits, and harvest (Leviticus 26:20)
49. Desperation and anguish (Leviticus 26:16)

It's important to note that these curses are listed in Leviticus 26 as consequences for disobeying God's commandments and breaking the covenant. They were specific to the Israelites in the context of their relationship with God and the covenant made with them at that time.

Exactly 49! What are the odds?

Comment: Did it add that last paragraph? I knew AI would eventually figure out the Torah is true!

Comment: Yes, I tried the other: "To provide a comprehensive list of all the curses in Ki Tavo would be lengthy and exceed the character limit for a single response. However, in summary, the curses in Ki Tavo are warnings of the consequences that would befall the Israelites if they failed to keep God's commandments, including curses related to their crops, livestock, health, enemies, and ultimately their exile from the Promised Land. The curses in Ki Tavo serve as a reminder of the importance of obedience to God's commands and the seriousness of the covenant relationship between God and the Israelites.

Comment: What order is this in?  [It is not the order of the Torah.]